# How do I standardize correct encoding from differnets sources with pd.read_csv and pd.to_csv?

Tags: pandas, encoding, utf-8, iso-8859-1

"I read files from different sources using pandas. Currently, I'm facing an issue with a Portuguese word 'Assembléia.' When I read this word with the 'utf-8' encoding and keep it in the DataFrame, everything works well. However, when I export it to a CSV, the word changes to 'assemblÃ©ia.' What should I do? I tried changing the encoding to 'latin1,' and it worked fine. But now, when I try to encode another file with 'latin1' as well, the code throws a UnicodeEncodeError."

this is a example with latin1

```
data = {'Palavra': ['assembléia']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

nome_arquivo_csv = r'C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Documents\cv - general\palavra_assembleia.csv'
df.to_csv(nome_arquivo_csv, index=False)
```

In this example, the CSV file displays the word 'assemblÃ©ia' instead of the expected 'Assembléia.' The problem is likely

Is there a way to standardize all encoding for files?

Comment: You face a [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) case: `'assembléia'.encode( 'utf-8').decode( 'cp1252')` returns `'assemblÃ©ia'`. The output file is written using `UTF-8` encoding correctly. How do you _read_ the file seeing the mojibake?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
df.to_csv(nome_arquivo_csv, index=False, encoding='utf-8')
```

Comment: does not working... the out keeps  assemblÃ©ia

Comment: @user202135 The problem is the tool used to view the CSV, not Python. The file is written correctly. The *viewer* is reading the file using the wrong encoding. Some viewers (like Excel) need `utf-8-sig` encoding, which writes a prefix to the file to hint that UTF8 should be used to decode the file